# How to disable debug SQL logs in Yesod development mode

Tags: sql, haskell, logging, yesod

Is it possible to disable `[Debug#SQL]` logs when running Yesod application in development with `yesod devel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for something like this in `Application.hs`

```
 pool <-
    flip runLoggingT logFunc $
      createPostgresqlPool
        (pgConnStr $ appDatabaseConf appSettings)
        (pgPoolSize $ appDatabaseConf appSettings)
```

and replace it with something like this

```
pool <-
    runNoLoggingT $
      createPostgresqlPool
        (pgConnStr $ appDatabaseConf appSettings)
        (pgPoolSize $ appDatabaseConf appSettings)
```

Using `runNoLoggingT` monad transformer is the key to make it work. You can also change the logging settings for migrations if you wish. As you can see, the application uses postgreSQL.